# Is there a difference between these conditional assignments which process default values?

Tags: php, variable-assignment

As part of validating a parameter (`$rowcount`) to a function in an MVC controller, so it might have been left blank, and retrieving a default value from the session (`$pp` for per page), I wrote this line of code in 2011:

```
$pp = $pp  &&  $pp != '' ? $pp : $rowcount;
```

I am wondering if I had been aware of some trick which makes that superior to what seems the more straightforward flavor:

```
$pp = $pp != '' ? $pp : $rowcount;
```

Maybe, that dual redundant checking?   Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`''` is always false, so the first statement has redundant conditions. Note that `isset($pp)` would *not* be redundant.